Can I find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ if $y=\int^{2x^2+2}_{x^2+4}t\tan\sqrt{4x+t}\mathrm{d}t$ by simply using substitution
I'm trying to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ with
$$y=\int^{2x^2+2}_{x^2+4}t\tan\sqrt{4x+t}\mathrm{d} t,x\ge -1$$ by simply using the substitution rule. I knew that I can plainly use the Leibniz's rule for differentiation of an integral with variable limits to evaluate it, but I found that the result produced by Leibniz rule is rather bizarre:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=4x(2x^2+2)\tan(\sqrt{2}(x+1))-2x(x^2+4)\tan(x+2)+\int^{2x^2+2}_{x^2+4}\frac{2t}{\sqrt{4x+t}}\sec^2\sqrt{4x+t}\mathrm{d}t
$$
and this is the cleanest form I can get so far. So I'm wondering can I get a more elegant result from using substitution.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Welcome to MSE. Have you tried a chain rule? Besides, please add some more contexts to make your question more specific. For example, you can add some trials you have done, or what's the source of that question.

You could try the substitution $u = \sqrt{4x+t}$ in the original integral, before you differentiate.

As @Gribouillis commented, using $u = \sqrt{4x+t}$
$$y=\int_{x+2 }^{ (x+1)\sqrt{2} }2 u \left(u^2-4 x\right) \tan (u),du$$ looks more pleasant
